# Why Wrappers are made around class

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am working in a project which uses pyqt4. Many place I see a situation like

```
class getWidget():
  @classmethod
  def get_line(cls,**args)
      return line(**args)

  @classmethod
  def get_label(cls,**args)
      return label(**args)

  @classmethod
  def get_button(cls,**args)
      return button(**args)





class line():
 ...
 ...

class label():
 ...
 ...

class button():
 ...
 ...
```

Whats the idea behind creating such a wrapper around BBB.

Comment: why do you/they use `cls` instead of `self` ?

Comment: These are class methods, So cls is used but this is just a convention, the place is important after the parentheses.

Comment: No, you should not do this; `self` is what is expected and you'll confuse people by doing otherwise. The Python convention is to use `self`. It's told in books. You can read these SO questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152850/is-it-possible-not-to-use-self-in-a-class and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984104/how-to-avoid-explicit-self

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how it has anything to do with pyqt4.

If the author did not leave any documentation, we can only speculate his/her intention.

I guess it is very likely the original author wants to implement some sort of factory pattern such that he/she can write code like this:

```
b = AAA.get_BBB(param1, param2, param3)
```

Comment: I thought it is some kind of programming trick/practice when making GUI application. That's why i mentioned pyqt. Thanks