# How many formal parameters does `def__init__(self,name)` have?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

How many formal parameters does

```
def __init__(self, name):
```

have?

One or two?

Is `self` counted as formal parameter?

If yes/no can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: What's your definition of a "formal parameter" it is an explicit argument and it is only convention that we use `self`, if could be called anything.

Comment: Well then what is an explicit argument ? I want to know how it works.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984104/how-to-avoid-explicit-self-in-python

Comment: Formal parameter is not a precise term - therefore question is unclear.

Comment: _I want to know how it works._ Why don't you ask how _lack_ of parameter is other languages works? Does result of function call depends on previous state of object? Yes it does. So why not make it explicit and pass it as a argument? `__init__` is slightly trickier, since previous state is an _empty_ state, but point still stands.

Comment: Check [What is the purpose of self?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self) it contains some good explanations