# TypeError: hola() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, class, methods, typeerror

This a simply code that I trying to access to a method in a class from another method in the same class but it is given me that error any help?

```
class menu:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b

    def suma(self):
        x=self.a+self.b
        print(x)

    def hola(): 
        menu.suma()


menu=menu(1,2)
menu.hola()
```

Comment: you need to def hola(self): , you are missing self......

Comment: change `def hola(): 
        menu.suma()` to `def hola(self): 
        self.suma()`

Comment: Good that help me a lot I appreciate your help a lot

Comment: @LeonardoRadilloescobar the answer that is marked as incorrect works but luckily, it is not the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to avoid explicit 'self' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984104/how-to-avoid-explicit-self-in-python)

You need an explicit self in python. The self argument is always passed in.

```
class menu:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b

    def suma(self):
        x=self.a+self.b
        print(x)

    def hola(self): 
        menu.suma()


menu=menu(1,2)
menu.hola()
```

Comment: Does your code work ?, have you tried it?