# Does python has something similar to _ENV in lua?

Tags: python

In Lua script, when i have to wirte too many lines like:

```
obj.age=17
obj.name="jack"
obj.country="US"
...
obj.weight=100
```

I can use `_ENV` to simpify the code:

```
_ENV=obj
age=17
name="jack"
country="US"
...
weight=100
```

Namely, I can avoid typing `obj.` repeatedly, is there a way in python to do like this? I searched on net buf found nothing.

I need to use python script as a configuration file, and the latter format seems better.

Comment: The classic [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)...
"I need to use python script as a configuration file" Does not seem like the best approach. Check `ini`, `json` or `yaml` file formats

Comment: Also, take a look to Python configparser https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html, it allows to define and manipulate config files very easily.

Answer (score 3):

Why not

```
obj = {
    'age': 17,
    'name': 'jack',
    'country': 'US',
    ...,
    'weight': 100
}
```

? Newlines need no `\` here, since they are inside a pair of braces.

Of course, this builds a dictionary, but do you really need an object of a specific class in a configuration?

Comment: If OP does need object access, (s)he could look into [`SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace), or [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it using [SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) (Python3 only)

```
import types
obj = types.SimpleNamespace(
    age=17
    name="jack"
    country="US"
    ...
    weight=100
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You really asked two questions in one.

For the second about storing configuration, you can

- write your vars in say, a 'config.py' module. Then `import config as cfg` and manipulate using `cfg.` qualified names. You can also `from config import *` for direct use but that's not recommended and you loose write capability in the original config module. They are copied into current namespace, not linked.
- simply use a dictionary to hold your settings like Walter said. They are the obvious builtin type for that.
- make your own Configuration class, instantiate `cfg`and manipulate attributes through `cfg.` qualifier.
- use a *shelf*, a *persistant dict* with the [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) module.
- Because shelves use *pickle* and this is a binary format used mostly in Python (I think)to store objects, you may prefer to use some more human oriented open format like suggested by DeepSpace and Cartucho (see configparser for `.ini`and so on).
- Much like with the class case, use a namedtuple or a SimpleNamespace (didn't know this one) like Wouda and luminousmen said.

Probably there are even more choices but I think the list looks enough for most tastes.

Now for the first question, that I think is a very good one, I am almost sure that the answer is no, you can't do that in Python. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984104/how-to-avoid-explicit-self-in-python) I found [this](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-must-self-be-used-explicitly-in-method-definitions-and-calls.htm) which is the reasoning for `self` use obligation. Safety, explicitness, and performance it looks. I suppose if it were to be allowed, you could use it too for `self`, and maybe that's why you can't.

I sometimes miss that feature too.