# Can python have class or instance methods that do not have "self" as the first argument?

Tags: python, oop, methods

Every single example I have seen of a *method* in a *class* in Python, has `self` as the first argument.  Is this true of all methods?  If so, couldn't python have been written so that this argument was just understood and therefore not needed?

Comment: and [What is the advantage of having this/self pointer mandatory explicit?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/910020)

Comment: instance methods are passed the instance as first argument, class methods the class

Comment: Based on one of the existing answers, this question isn't a 100% duplicate. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Certainly sounds like a duplicate, granted, but the answers to that other question really aren't getting at my question, with the exception of one answer that links to Guido's blog, and I can't read that to confirm right now because of a firewall problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want a method that doesn't need to access `self`, use [`staticmethod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod):

```
class C(object):
    def my_regular_method(self, foo, bar):
        pass
    @staticmethod
    def my_static_method(foo, bar):
        pass

c = C()
c.my_regular_method(1, 2)
c.my_static_method(1, 2)
```

If you want access to the *class*, but not to the instance, use [`classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```
class C(object):
    @classmethod
    def my_class_method(cls, foo, bar):
        pass

c.my_class_method(1, 2)
```

Comment: Just learned something new.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

static methods don't need self<strike>, they operate on the class</strike>

see a good explanation of static here:
[Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

Comment: Static methods don't operate on the class; they have no reference to the class other than the class name itself.