# What is the best way of accessing instance variable inside class in Java?

Tags: java, oop, this, instance-variables

I've just started learning Java *and it's great*. One thing I need to understand that in a class we can access instance variable in two ways:

```
class Box {

    // Instance variables
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int depth;

    // First way
    public void set_volume(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.width = a;
        this.height = b;
        this.depth = c;
    }

    // Second way
    public void set_volume_v2(int a, int b, int c) {
        width = a;
        height = b;
        depth = c;
    }

}
```

**Here**, Instance variable is accessible without `this` keyword and with it. So what's the best way? OR What's the difference between them?

Comment: Both are ok. You typically use the `this` keyword when the field name is hidden by a argument.

Comment: In your case both are same, as there is no ambiguity in resolving local and instance variables as their name differs ! Sometimes it is better to use `this` inside a lengthy method just to be more clear in identifying instance variables and local variables.

Comment: Search before you post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725770/should-the-java-this-keyword-be-used-when-it-is-optional , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516291/the-use-of-this-in-java, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/113430/what-is-the-accepted-style-for-using-the-this-keyword-in-java

Comment: @Shiva The 3 links don't answer it. By the way nice attempt.

Comment: One comment for put-on-holders that the 3 answers I got are all same they don't differ by opinion. So, this question no-way looks to me an opinion based question.

Comment: "what's the best way?" is a question asking for opinions. The other question "What's the difference between them?" is perfectly answerable though. I would recommend editing out the first question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way is to always use  `this`

```
 this.width = a;
```

So that we never confuse between the argument names and instance variables.

One small example  to confuse is

```
  public void set_volume_v2(int width) {
        width = width;
    }
```

So when you write `this.width` we are making it clear that it's instance variable.

Comment: That's why all parameters should be final. Your example would have a compilation error if the width parameter was final. Not the downvoter btw.

Answer (score 5):

Using `this` will allow you to make sure you are referencing the instance variable instead of the argument, should they share the same name.

This is often thought as a best practice in instance methods and constructors.

Otherwise your two methods are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Instance variable should be access with `this` keyword **it eleminates the confusion of same name of local veriable**. This would ignore below kind of problem -

```
public void set_volume_v2(int width, int height, int depth) {
    width = width;
    height = height;
    depth = depth;
}
```

Here for more preference local veriable would be used.

```
public void set_volume_v2(int width, int height, int depth) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.depth = depth;
}
```

And this.width make sure that is instance variable and width is local variable.

Comment: You will only need the `this` keyword in that particular case. It's perfectly fine to reference a field without it.

Comment: @Bart That is the reason. We should always habituate to use `this` ,  so you need not to remember any cases :)